# Visual Studio 2015 Apache Cordova - Build with ios-app in real device connected to PC

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, visual-studio-2015

i'm tryng to build an ios app in a iPad connected to my PC. I haven't mac so i use a remote mac (i have a macincloud managed server).
I have a paid developer apple account, I dowloaded ios_certificate and provisioning profile (and installed it in the registered-ipad).
I launch remotebuild from mac terminal, the ios-configuration in tool>option of visual studio is ok and the connection is ok.
I open my project in visual studio, set ios and local device, but when i try to compile the app i have an error, so i have some questions:
1)maybe i need a macincloud dedicated server? (i have a valid ios-developer-certificate but can't install it in xcode because i'm not administrator of tha remote mac).
2) i need to install visual studio in remote mac or it is enough have visual studio installed in my pc?
3)any other suggestions?
P.S. If i compile the ios-app in a generic ios-simulator with remotebuild + f5 in visual studio it works fine.

But if i try to compile in local device i have the following error:
Gravità Codice  Descrizione Progetto    File    Riga    Stato eliminazione
Errore      Error: Errore di compilazione remota restituito dal server di compilazione La compilazione non è riuscita. Errore: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/user134231/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/53300/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,tennispiu.xcworkspace,-scheme,tennispiu,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,tennispiu.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/user134231/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/53300/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/user134231/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/53300/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch: 1

Thank you if you would like to help me.

Comment: Perhaps you might like to format the question to be more readable? Also, try to keep your posts to be one question.

Comment: i'm sorry, i know, my english is terrible...

Comment: So my first question is: is it possible compiling an ios-app with Visual Studio Apache Cordova and install it on a real device connected to my PC, if i'm not an administrator of the remote-mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ios target build you need to install xcode and other stuffs (remotebuild agent, npm..) on remote mac.

Please follow official TACO guide available here at paragraph **"Mac OS Installation"**, (its a bit long to post here):

[Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova: iOS Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/ios-guide)

Comment: Thank you for your response. On remote mac (where i'm not administrator) are already installed remotebuild agent, npm,... and when i launch remotebuild in secure mode and i try to connect to the remotebuild agent after set ios-configuration with rigth host, port and security pin, Visual studio connects fine to remote agent; Xcode is installed on remote mac (version 9.2). But when i try to compile i have the error that i posted up and i can't install my app on the ipad connected to my PC.

Comment: Look at build.log on mac side in  /Users/user134231/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/53300/  folder, or in Output-> build window in visual studio for more specific error.. To increase verbosity of logging go in Tools>Options>Project and Solutions>Build and Run> MSBuild project output verbosity and set it to DIAGNOSTIC.  Under output window of visual studio you are able to see full build log and error stack.

Comment: I think the problem is IPA installation in local device, because itunes does not long support installation of developer signed ipa. I build with target "remote device" then i install my IPA with xcode on physical local MAC.  Check build.log and look for something about installation or sign.

Comment: Thank's Frix33, you are very helpful for me. After your suggestions i read in output window the following error:

Comment: (A parte l'assurdità di due utenti italiani che si parlano in inglese)  please post full error, is not visible in above comment ;)

Comment: Thank's Frix33, you are very helpful for me. After your suggestions, i read in output window the following error: "Code Signing Error No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found:  No "iOS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID "XXXXXXXXX" with a private key was found". So i think that the issue would be i can't put my ios_development.cer in keychan of remote-mac (i'm not administrator for that remote mac) and it is missing. Is it possible that it is so?

Comment: If it search "distribution" certificate you need a "distribution (store)" certificate installed in MAC keychain, For development build choose "Debug" instead of "Release" in visual studio option before build (on top midle combobox). You also need a development certificate in MAC keychain.

Comment: Qua mi sa che si arrabbiano se continuo a scrivere, ma mi piacerebbe ancora avere suggerimenti da te (in italiano stante il mio ingese)...

Comment: Se non puoi installare i cert sul mac puoi fare poco mi sa, se serve aiuto comunque puoi contattarmi sulla chat di stackoverflow, qua non c'è nulla per mandare messaggi privati tra utenti..

Comment: Non penso di poter usare la chat perchè sono nuovo di qua. Comunque per il momento ti ringrazio che sei stato gentilissimo ad indirizzarmi su quale potesse essere l'errore.

Comment: Fiugurati ;) Flagga la risposta come chiusa che servono solamente 20 punti per il privilegio chat, ci arrivi con poco